# Restart app on receiving sms or call

Tags: android

I want to know what exactly happens when app is Settings->Manage Applications->force closed.
Does it calls onDestroy().I want to restart my app if it is force closed by user. How to do this. I was wondering if I can rertart it on receving SMS or call using broadcastReceivers.

Yup I am doing the same thing. I am checking ic my service is running using this code, but it always display "service running" Toast 
      boolean isServiceRunning = AppSettings.getServiceRunning(context);
     if (isServiceRunning)
         {
               Toast.makeText(context,"service running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else 
         {
               Toast.makeText(context,"service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  I am writing this in onReceive() of broadcastReceiver 
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force close is:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

> Register your receiver in the AndroidManifest. That way it will be called even when your app 
>   is not running: [R.styleable.AndroidManifestReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceiver)
>
> You could then check in the BroadcastReceiver whether the service is
>   still running and restart it.
>
> See for example the class SmSForwarder [here](https://github.com/flurischt/sms2HTTP/blob/master/src/ch/flurischt/sms2http/SmsForwarder.java). The broadcastreceiver
>   does not need to run because it is registerend in the
>   [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/flurischt/sms2HTTP/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) (see line 29). Android will start the
>   Broadcastreceiver as soon as the Intent
>   "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" is sent.

Comment: Yup I am doing the same thing. I am checking ic my service is running using this code, but it always display "service running" Toast           boolean isServiceRunning = AppSettings.getServiceRunning(context);  
  if (isServiceRunning)
  {
   Toast.makeText(context,"service running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   
  } 
  else 
  { 
   Toast.makeText(context,"service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
  }                            I am writing this in onReceive() of broadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

Restarting an app after user force closed it might be considered as a sign of malware. It's highly discouraged. Having said that, if you really want to restart it back on, use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and check for app status every hour or so.

Instead of SMS or phone call, it might be a better idea to catch `android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON` Intent and restart your application.

Comment: ok. but should I restart my mainActivity using Intent or start service?